# Python Unicode character printing - encoding issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I am getting a Unicode character from a form input field using

```
input_string = form["text"].value.decode('utf-8')
```

According to the debugger, the value is `u'Щ'` which is of type unicode.
I now want to print Щ to the console, but `print input_string.encode('utf-8')` results in "Ð©".

How do I successfully get the Щ character to print in the console?

Comment: The console must be configured to use UTF-8 also. Which operating system and which console program do you use?

Comment: I am using PyCharm on Windows, but I would also like to send this character back to the server. I am currently using `self.wfile.write(input_string)` in the do_POST function of a BaseHTTPRequestHandler.

Answer (score 0):

The code point for your character 'Щ' is `d0a9` in hexadecimals. That translates to Ð© in the [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set. UTF-8 encoding always uses printable characters when seen as Latin. So you always get one or more printable characters when printing out UTF-8 encoding, in this case two.

You need a console that is configured to use UTF-8 when printing your UTF-8 strings to output. Obviously the console needs to support UTF-8 to do this. Furthermore, that console needs to use a Font that contains this particular character.